# NOT EXISTS without a common column

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have 3 tables as below,

```
Table - 1: TMP (Column: PARTS)

Table - 2: BOM (Column: ID - which is a primary key in table 3)

Table - 3: PROD (Column1: ID - Primary key in this table, Column2: PARTS)
```

Now I have to find the list of parts from `Table1` which does not exists in `Table2`.

I tried the below query but the performance is too bad.

```
SELECT PARTS FROM TMP WHERE ((TMP.PARTS) NOT IN (SELECT (SELECT PARTS FROM PROD WHERE PROD.ID = BOM.ID) FROM BOM));
```

I tried using `NOT EXISTS` but not getting the desired result.

Comment: For which database system are you asking? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? ...

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
SELECT PARTS 
FROM TMP 
WHERE PARTS NOT IN 
            (SELECT PARTS 
                FROM PROD P
                JOIN BOM B ON B.ID = P.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all parts **except** products that appear in BOM.

```
select parts from tmp
except
select parts from prod where id in (select id from bod);
```

(Not every DBMS supports this standard keyword, though. Which is why you should always tag SQL questions with the DBMS involved. I think MySQL doesn't support `EXCEPT` at all. Oracle calls it `MINUS`. Most other RDBMS should support `EXCEPT`.)

Answer (score 0):

Bro Try this. Using join is a much faster way to any else.

```
SELECT PARTS 
FROM TMP 
left join BOM on 
    TMP.PARTS   =   BOM.PARTS
join PROD on
    BOM.ID  =   PROD.ID
where BOM.ID is null
```